# how to increase the zoom level(zoom scale) from 21 to 23 in android(even thought their is no google map at at scale i just want to zoom to that point)

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition =
    new CameraPosition.Builder().target(bbx.getCenter()).zoom(23).build();
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code to zoom to a specific location.

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, Constants.MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL), this);
        googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

where loc is your `Location` object and replace `Constants.MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL` with 23 in your case.
 *Note:- you have to implement `GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener`

Also the max zoom level cannot be more than 21. "   the desired zoom level, in the range of 2.0 to 21.0. Values below this range are set to 2.0, and values above it are set to 21.0. Increase the value to zoom in. Not all areas have tiles at the largest zoom levels.".Please reference [This](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#public-methods).

Comment: thanks, but i need to increase the zoom levels more than 21 in google map.